# Error handling with tar and keep-old-files option

Tags: tar

I am unpacking tar files with the `--keep-old-files` option so that I don't clobber files that are already there.  The annoying thing is that this causes tar to produce an error code #2 (fatal error) when a file is already there.

The reason it's important to me that this should not be considered an error is because my script logs when a file is successfully unpacked and then uses this log in order to not re-unpack that tar file.

I could just ignore this error completely, not log, and trust that no files will be overwritten but there are two problems with this:  it generates a lot of error messages, and there are many files, so it's inefficient for me to open tar once for every file.

Is there any way I can use `--keep-old-files`, ignore the errors generated by existing files, and not ignore other errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is apparently by design - from the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html):

> To be even more cautious and prevent existing files from being replaced, use the `--keep-old-files` (`-k`) option. It causes tar to refuse to replace or update a file that already exists, i.e., a file with the same name as an archive member prevents extraction of that archive member. Instead, it reports an error.

The git repository does contain a [patch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/diff/?id=7a5a3708cb8b33494cd6ac64bfe163f631a33edf&id2=d0dd0473f75476447f51522a23f790ecc0bfc4db) that introduces a `--skip-old-files` parameter, so this could be solved in a future GNU `tar` version:

> ```
> +A new option --skip-old-files is introduced, which acts exactly as
> +--keep-old-files, except that it does not treat existing files as
> +errors.  Instead it just silently skips them.  An additional level of
> +verbosity can be obtained by using the option --warning=existing-file
> +together with this option.
> ```

The patch hasn't made it into an [official release](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) yet, though.